# How to get Accumulator result using morphia in mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm using Morphia with MongoDB in Java, I like to get a number of records in aggregation query like that:

```
AggregationPipeline pipCount = ds.createAggregation(MyTable.class)
            .match(query1)
            .match(query2)
            .unwind("transactions")
            .match(query3)
            .group("_id", grouping("_id"), grouping("count", new Accumulator("$sum", 1)));
Iterator<MyTable> result = pipCount.aggregate(MyTable.class);
```

I need to use grouping("_id") to remove duplicate result and then count the result but can't find any way to read sum value...
any idea?

Sample Data:

```
{
    "_id": "00000222",
    "create_date": ISODate("2015-05-06T07:20:31.000+0000"),
    "update_date": ISODate("2015-05-06T07:20:31.000+0000"),
    "payment": 70.0,
    "fee": 0.0,
    "type": "RECURRING",
    "currency": "USD",
    "status": "OK",
    "transactions": [{
        "_id": "111111223",
        "amount": 1260.0,
        "fee_type": "VARIABLE_ADD",
        "fee_rate": 2.75,
        "status": "ERROR",
        "charges": [{
            "_id": "2222223344",
            "amount": 1000.0,
            "recurring": true,
            "firstTime": false,
            "oneTime": true,
        }, {
            "_id": "222222222233221",
            "amount": 70.0,
            "recurring": true,
            "firstTime": true,
            "oneTime": true,
        }]
    }],
    "users": {
        "_id": "33333333332212",
        "update_date": ISODate("2015-12-18T08:03:35.000+0000"),
        "user_id": "sdjfhsd@skjksdf.com",
        "first_name": "dsjfj",
        "last_name": "skdfjf",
    }
}
```

Result: 1

Comment: Why are we grouping by _id twice ? Please consider adding  sample doc and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. You don't need an extra grouping. The first group will take care of duplicates while counting the sum and project the count and map the response to document and read the count.

```
import org.bson.Document; 

AggregationPipeline pipCount = datastore.createAggregation(MyTable.class)
            .match(query1)
            .match(query2)
            .unwind("somethingID")
            .match(query3)
            .group("_id", grouping("count", new Accumulator("$sum", 1)))
            .project(Projection.projection("count"));

    Iterator<Document> result = pipCount.aggregate(Document.class);

    while (result.hasNext()) {
        Document document = result.next();
        Integer count = document.getInteger("count");
    }
```

Comment: do you know a better way to count all records of that AggregationPipeline? for unknown reason this way is not working anymore.

Comment: do you see any error ? did your `MyTable` class structure change ? I don't think there is any other way than summing rows in group stage

Comment: it returns a list of ID's with count = 0, instead of just one record with total count!!

Comment: you can replace `group("_id", grouping("count", new Accumulator("$sum", 1)))` with `group(null, grouping("count", new Accumulator("$sum", 1)))` for one row with count of all records, but I'm not sure if this is even going to work when previously getting list of ids with count 0.

Comment: One way to test by adding one stage at a time and observing the result.  You'll know where the records are filtered.

Comment: group(null,... is not working because group is overloaded , but String str=null, group(str,... is working. Thanks

Comment: Try `group((String)null, grouping("count", new Accumulator("$sum", 1)))` but I doubt this is the problem.